# Multiple grouping and sorting in Collection entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lambda, spring-data-jpa

I have entities as shown below -

```
@Entity
public class Certification {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
        
    private String role;  // can have values like "Architect", "Developer", "Business Practioner"
    private int score;
    private Date expiryDate
        
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "solution_id")
    private Solution solution;
      
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "region_id")
    private Region region;
}


@Entity
public class Solution {
  private String name;  //can have values like "Analytics", "Campaign", "Marketo"
}


@Entity
public class Region{
    private String name;  //can have values like "EMEA", "APAC", "JAPAN" & "AMERICAS"
}


@Entity
public class Employee {
@OnetoMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Certification> certifications
}
```

After pulling the employee certifications, I need to do multiple grouping and sorting and then pull the count of certification under a specific role. First I group by Solution name, then by Region, and then by Role. Each of these groups needs to be sorted alphabetically. For example, under solution group, "Analytics" should come first then "Campaign". Under region "APAC" should come first then "EMEA". And under the roles group, "Architecture" should come first then "Business Prationer".

```
{
  "expertise": [
    {
      "solutionName": "Analytics",
      "regions": [
        {
          "name": "APAC",
          "roles": [
            {
              "name": "Architect",
              "certifiedEmployees": 12
            },
            {
              "name": "Business Practitioner",
              "certifiedEmployees": 9
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "EMEA",
          "roles": [
            {
              "name": "Architect",
              "certifiedEmployees": 12
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "solutionName": "Campaign",
      "regions": [
        {
          "name": "APAC",
          "roles": [
            {
              "name": "Architect",
              "certifiedEmployees": 12
            },
            {
              "name": "Business Practitioner",
              "certifiedEmployees": 9
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "EMEA",
          "roles": [
            {
              "name": "Architect",
              "certifiedEmployees": 12
            },
            {
              "name": "Back-end Developer",
              "certifiedEmployees": 9
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using Collectors.groupingBy and Comparator.comparing but unable to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way to group a list using java streams and groupingBy. It's short and helps me avoid a lot of coding

```
credentials.stream().collect(groupingBy(c -> c.getSolution().getName(), groupingBy(c -> c.getRegion().getName())));
```